# Getting InternalError: Unread result found after inserting new data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm new to python and MySQL but I've been trying to program a schema which has a user entity with 2 subtypes: **student** and **instructor**. When I use this function

```
def create_user(userName, email, Instructor):
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
generatedKey = uuid.uuid4()
id = generatedKey.bytes
generatedKey = uuid.uuid4()
PCID = generatedKey.bytes

sql = "INSERT INTO User(UserID,UserName, UserEmail) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = (id, userName, email)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
if(Instructor):
    sql = "INSERT INTO PostCreator(PCID, CreatorType) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (PCID, "Instructor")
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Instructor(InstructorId,PCID) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (id, PCID)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
else:
    sql = "INSERT INTO PostCreator(PCID, CreatorType) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (PCID, "Student")
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Student(StudentId,PCID) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (id, PCID)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
print("Registered", userName)
```

to create a student I don't have any issues. However when I try to create an instructor the system either times out, or creates an instructor but and following calls on the system results in a: InternalError: Unread result found after inserting new data.

I have no idea why making a student is ok but instructors don't work. Their tables are created the same in the SQL.

Comment: check for errors in your code

Comment: Any ideas where? The inserting code is basically the same for the instructors and students and their tables were set up the same in SQL.

Comment: as you have obnlx problems with instructor make https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html and see if mysl has a problem. As we don't know how your tables are not how yyou connect ssl ssh ... you have to help yourself